# Permissions issue with conky getting ESSID, tried all the usual

Tags: 12.10, setcap

Conky can't get my wireless essid due to the wl kernel module and neither could my normal user account. If I did 
    `sudo iwconfig wlan0`
it was fine, and if I ran conky as root it was fine, but I don't want to do that.

The solution was the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230740/linux-how-to-get-wireless-ssid-without-root-permission) more specifically [this link](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/) is what I followed, and it worked great. For awhile.. Now it doesn't work anymore and I'm not sure why.

It worked for my user acount. If I run iwconfig I see all the wireless info. If I enter
    `${exec iwconfig wlan0}` 
in my conky config conky spits out all the wireless info, including ssid. But using conky's built in
    `${wireless_essid wlan0}`
returns nothing for ESSID and 'Not-Associated' for the AP MAC.

I've tried all I can, including
    `sudo chmod u+s /sbin/iwconfig`
(which also worked before, but now fails to work for conky)

I should also clarify that I edited the udev rule to rename eth1 to wlan0, as eth1 is the standard interface name that comes up with the wl driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so the solution for anyone else that ends up here:

`sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/conky`

Details are [here](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/) but basically you need to give conky permissions to use the network interface.